# What are the benefits to use Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday google Introduction new developer tools that name is [Android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).what are the benefits use Android studio instead eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It described the developers site itself. To get you know I just copied it here:

1. Gradle-based build support.
2. Android-specific refactoring and quick fixes.
3. Lint tools to catch performance, usability, version compatibility
   and other problems.
4. ProGuard and app-signing capabilities.
5. Template-based wizards to create common Android designs and
   components.
6. A rich layout editor that allows you to drag-and-drop UI components,
   preview layouts on multiple screen configurations, and much more.

I am not using it but will try to get the new capability that is auto build in this new IDE.

Comment: What is this "ProGuard and app-signing capabilities" means ?